# Laravel array object rule

Tags: php, laravel

I send an array to a REST API. How can I add a rule for the array?

Also I want to add `field_name_id`, `field_input_type` and `field_caption` as required fields.

I don't know how can I access the array in Laravel rules. Can someone help me?

```
$rules = [
    'name'  => 'required',
    'forms' => 'array'
]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sending the array of objects in JSON format to the Laravel REST API ?

Comment: @Pratik no i send an objects of array format. That screenshot from response, i response inputs to share with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses dot notation to validate arrays and it's nested fields.

```
$rules = [
    'forms.field_name_id' => 'required', 
    'forms.field_input_type'=> 'required', 
    'forms.field_caption' => 'required',
]
```

You can also validate each value within the array. For example, If you want the *caption* to be unique:

```
$rules = [
    'forms.*.field_caption' => 'unique:captions,caption',
]
```

Here are the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validating-arrays) for more information on how to use them